# How long does it take for gas to settle down under earth's gravity?

Tags: thermodynamics, newtonian-gravity, ideal-gas, estimation, gas

I was discussing about ideal gas with my colleague the other day, and these questions come up in our conversation.

> Lets say we have 1 mole ideal gas in a perfectly insulating cube box of size $1m^3$, and just put it on the floor at room temperature.
>
> How will gravity affect the distribution of the gas? 
> Will it ever settle down?

I honestly never consider this, and can't quite come up with a solution for it.

Comment: In theory gravity will cause a vertical pressure gradient inside the box, but over a height of 1 metre the effect of this will be insignificant, and probably negligible compared to thermal motions of the gas.

Comment: That is treated as an isothermal atmosphere, and the pressure is slightly higher at the bottom than the top, in a very fixed and precise manner. It is one of the possible stepping stones towards an understanding of statistical thermodynamics.

Comment: I think people should focus on what this person is actually asking about - how does the gas achieve equilibrium and what is the order of magnitude of how long it takes. Lots of people seem to be focusing rather on calculating the magnitude of the pressure difference in equilibrium, which is not in any way what this person is asking about. I acknowledge that given the numbers provided by OP (and assuming room temperature) the effect is small, but that's obviously not conceptually what they're interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equilibrium pressure distribution of an isothermal gas as a function of the height $h$ is given by the [barometric height formula](https://www.tec-science.com/mechanics/gases-and-liquids/barometric-formula-for-an-isothermal-atmosphere/)

$$p=p_0\cdot e^{-\frac{h}{H}}$$

with

$$H=\frac{kT}{mg}$$

the so called 'scale height' where $m$ is the mass of the molecules, $T$ their temperature, $g$ the gravitational acceleration and $k$ the Boltzmann constant (I am using the Boltzmann constant $k$ here instead of the specific gas constant $R$ as in the reference link).

As the temperature $T$ is assumed constant here, the same relationship applies therefore also for the number density $n$ of the gas (as $p=nkT$)

$$n=n_0\cdot e^{-\frac{h}{H}}$$

Any pressure differences in a volume will generally be levelled out with the speed of sound, so for a volume of the size of the order of $1 m$, this will happen in a couple of milliseconds.

For standard (sea level) pressure on the Earth's surface, the scale height $H$ is of the order of $10 km$ though, so for $h=1m$, the argument of the exponential function is very small, of the order of $10^{-4}$. So the pressure at the bottom and the top of the volume will differ only by this small relative amount. But it will be there. Any initial pressure difference withing the volume will settle to this state within milliseconds.

Reaching equilibrium state will take somewhat longer though if the gas in the volume is initially not isothermal throughout. The pressure $p$ will still settle within milliseconds, but not the density $n$ and the temperature $T$ separately, only their product ($p=nkT$). The density will only settle once the temperature has become constant throughout the volume. We can obtain a rough estimate for how long this takes by calculating how long an air molecule would take to diffuse randomly through the volume. This depends obviously on the gas density in the volume. At standard (sea level) pressure the number density is $2.7\cdot 10^{19}/cm^3$. However $1 m^3$ at this pressure contains 42.3 moles. You stated there should only be 1 mole in the box, so the density in this case would only be $2.7\cdot 10^{19}/42.3/cm^3 = 6.4\cdot 10^{17}/cm^3$. If we take the cross section for two molecules colliding as $q=10^{-16} cm^2$, the mean free path with regard to collisions is therefore

$$l=\frac{1}{n\cdot q} =  \frac{1}{6.4\cdot 10^{17} \cdot 10^{-16}} cm =\frac{1}{64} cm =\frac{1}{6400} m$$

As the molecule does not move in straight line through the volume but performs a random walk, it will therefore have to cover a distance

$$L=6400^2\cdot \frac{1}{6400} m = 6400 m$$

to move from one end of the box to the other (the square function here is a statistical property for random walks which implies that the number of steps required to translate a given net distance is proportional to the square of the latter).

As the mean thermal speed of air molecules at room temperature would be about $500 m/sec$, it would therefore take about $6400/500 sec = 13 sec$ for the volume to level out any initial temperature differences and become effectively isothermal. After this time the density would then adjust to the barometric distribution as well.

Comment: Is diffusion typically regarded as the main mechanism by which a gas comes to thermal equilibrium?

Comment: @AXensen No, in general there may be of course other mechanisms like convection and radiation, but in this case (sealed box with just air inside) we do not have to consider these.